# jquery select tooltips not yet visible

Tags: jquery, html, css, tooltip

On my website, I have a section of the page that contains elements you can hover over to reveal a tooltip:

[image]

I have a zoom in and zoom out feature where I adjust the css zoom property of the div containing these elements.  Zooming in and out also adjusts the size of the tooltip font, but I want to keep the tooltip font size constant regardless of zoom size.

I thought I would be able to do this by adjusting the size of the font when the user zooms in:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $('.zoomOutIcon').click(function(){
          var currentZoom = parseFloat($('.jOrgChart').css('zoom'));
          $('.jOrgChart').css('zoom', currentZoom - 0.25); 
          var current_label_font_size = parseFloat($('.tooltip').attr('font-size'));
          $('.tooltip').attr('font-size', current_label_font_size*1.25);
         }
    });
```

However, it's not able to find the tooltip elements with $('.tooltip') because they are not yet loaded on the page until the user hovers over the element.  How can I set a css property of elements not yet loaded on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem, I destroy the tooltips every time the user zooms in or out of the div and recreate the tooltips specifying the "template" option, which I can use to pass the a class that specifies the desired font-size:

**javascript:**

```
  function setFontSize(){
     var currentZoom = $('.jOrgChart').css('zoom');
     if(currentZoom == 0.75){

      $('.stepNode').tooltip('destroy');

      $('.stepNode').slice(1, $('.stepNode').length-1).tooltip({
        template: '<div class="tooltip smaller"><div class="tooltip-arrow"></div><div class="tooltip-inner"></div></div>'
      });
    });
   }

  $('.zoomInIcon').click(function(){
    $('.jOrgChart').css('zoom', currentZoom + 0.25);
    setFontSize();
  }
```

**css**

```
.tooltip.smaller{
  font-size: 14px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.zoomOutIcon').click(function(){
          var current_label_font_size = parseFloat($('.tooltip').attr('font-size'));
          $('.tooltip').attr('font-size', current_label_font_size*1.25);
      });
 })
```

Comment: my code is already wrapped in a document.ready, sorry I didn't include it in my snippet.